# how to properly replace logo with text in header

Tags: php, wordpress, indentation

In `header.php` have a `code` that insert a logo into the place:

```
<div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo<?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?> show-for-large-up<?php } ?>">
                <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="logolink">
                        <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" class="logoimg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

(upper left corner):
[image]

In order to have a logotext instead of the `png` file, I've used the following code with no errors in the console but I'm pretty insecure being a noob in `php coding`. Is this the proper way (incuding the indentation) to have the [desired result](http://goo.gl/DkuFmq) ?

```
<div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo<?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?> show-for-large-up<?php } ?>">
                <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { ?>
                    <a class="logotext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
                    title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
                    rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right and I hope you're doing it in the child theme.

Here is more refined version of your code which will render Blog Title or text logo in case you don't have the Image Logo uploaded. If, however, the image logo is uploaded, it will use image.

```
<div class="small-7 medium-4 columns logo<?php if ($header_style == 'style1') { ?> show-for-large-up<?php } ?>">
            <?php if ($header_style == 'style2') { ?>
            <?php if (empty($logo)) { ?>                
             <a class="logotext" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
                title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
                rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
                </a>                
            <?php }else{ ?>
               <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="logolink">
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" class="logoimg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion code and for your confirmation. Actually I've made this modification directly in the header.php file of the main theme keeping a backup of the original file. Lately I've started to study the way a child theme works and I'll try to implement all the custom codes and settings approaching this method asap, before the next theme/plugins update.Btw. any code indenting app verification tool recomendation? Kind regards,